# the method problem and the difference between url and path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

when i read the book "Aglie web development with rails 4th",i found the code

```
<%= button_to 'Add to Cart', line_items_path(:product_id => product) %>
```

what's the difference if i use `"line_items_url"`  and the code doesn't has the method like `:method=>:post`,

why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `path` version produces relative urls such as `/order/34/lines/` while the url version produces a full url such as `http://localhost:3000/order/34/lines/`.

The second form is often used in mailers when the user click a link in a mail client or in an external webmail.

In your site you won't notice any difference.

Moreover the `:method=>:post` option will produce a post request to your webserver. It will do that by adding a javascript code which will create a form on the fly, add parameters to it and do a `submit` call to send your browser to the requested page with a post method.

Comment: @YuLong you're welcome. You should accept the answer if you found useful to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The `_url` helper generates an URL that includes the protocol and host 
name.  The `_path` helper generates only the path portion.